# How can typoscript forward "current"-value through TEMPLATE cObject into subparts?

Tags: templates, typo3, typoscript

I am using Typo3 CMS 7.6.4. I want to forward the "current"-value through a TEMPLATE cObject in order to use the value in its subparts.

```
lib.TEMPLATE_RENDER_OBJECT = TEMPLATE
lib.TEMPLATE_RENDER_OBJECT {
  template = TEXT
  template.value = <!-- ###SUBPART### begin -->some content<!-- ###SUBPART### end -->

  current = 1

  subparts {
    SUBPART = TEXT
    SUBPART {
      current = 1
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately the TEMPLATE cObject loads its own content into the "current"-value, what is also noted in the [TypoScriptReference for the TEMPLATE cObject](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Template/Index.html):

> [...] current-value is loaded with the content of each subpart [...]

So the upper *lib.TEMPLATE_RENDER_OBJECT* creates something like **"some content"** (instead of using the initial "current"-value as I intended).

---

Is it possible to disable this behavior of TEMPLATE or to restore the initial "current"-value?

Comment: Just a short question (maybe a little bit off topic). Why do you still use HTML based templates and subparts/ markers? I recommend using the FLUIDTEMPLATE cObject (see https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Fluidtemplate/Index.html) which allows much more flexibility. Since it's a TYPO3 7 you should avoid working with such old school stuff which will be removed sooner or later. Furthermore I would stop naming your TS libs all in upper case. Move to lowerCamelCase or something like that.

Comment: @Björn I wouldn't say, that I still use HTML based templates. It's more like I use a CMS, typo3, typoscript and these templates for the first time. Actually this method of having a HTML document containing the needed HTML structures, rearranging these structures and filling the contents as needed without introducing new tags seems to me more easy (for my use case, because I am able to develop the HTML structures using my standard browser). To be honest I also have to say that I did not try FLUIDTEMPLATEs till now.

Comment: @Björn And yes, your question being maybe a little bit off topic is yet certainly off question.

Answer (score 0):

A short answer is: It is not possible to forward the initially set "current"-value into the subparts of a TEMPLATE cObject.

I read this from [lines 69-77 and lines 126-131 from the php source code for this type](https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/bd0c7f6ca9cb3093bd647e85035e9f36bf1e9e86/typo3/sysext/frontend/Classes/ContentObject/TemplateContentObject.php). The "current"-value for every subpart is replaced there. On the other hand for every mark the initially set "current"-value is not overridden. So this is not handled consitently. But please forgive me if I make a mistake here, because this is the first time I look into php source code.

A solution could be to extend the existing source code for TEMPLATE e.g. by introducing a new flag for keeping the "current"-value. Then this extended source code could be used by a USER cObject.